# error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge: main/projects/banking_web/WebContent/WEB-INF/security/RIBprivate.key

Tags: git

while trying to git pull , facing the issue. I followed some git commands,
git clean -f -d
git reset --hard
git fetch --all

But still encountered the same issue.

expectations is to pull the latest code in my local.

Answer (score 0):

1. Solution:

   Go to the specified path till security, Delete the RIBprivate.key
   file . do a mvn clean install, it will resolve the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).